# Replace \\ with \ in python

Tags: python

I Have a string having path of folder like below

```
>>> path
'\\\\sdgte\\ssdfdaa\\asfdsf'
```

I want to replace \\ with \ . I tried to replace but does not work as below

```
>>> path.replace('\\','\')
File "<input>", line 1
path.replace('\\','\')
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Now try: `>>> len('\\')` on your system.

Answer (score 8):

There is no "\\" in the string. If you print it instead of looking at its **representation** you'll see the value that the string actually contains.

```
>>> print path
\\sdgte\ssdfdaa\asfdsf
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the escape charachter '\' to escape each \ in your string

```
path.replace('\\\\','\\')
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably don't need to replace anything.  `\` is a special character in python that means "the next character, literally" in string literals.  That is, if you want a string, containg a backslash, you'd probably type `"\\"`:

```
>>> len('\\')
1
>>> print '\\'
\
>>> print '\\\\foo\\bar'
\\foo\bar
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting that SyntaxError is the same reason you're seeing the doubled backslashes to begin with: backslash is the "escape" character, used to indicate the start of a special sequence, like "\n" for line feed, which would otherwise be difficult to represent in a string. The backslash character itself therefore has to be represented by a double backslash.

On the other hand, if you don't need to use any escape sequences within a string, you can preface the string with "r" instead of doubling the backslashes:

<s>path.replace(r'\\', r'\')</s>

```
path.replace(r'\\', '\\')
```

"r" indicates a "raw" string.

Comment: `r'\\' == '\\\\'`. `r'\'` raises a SyntaxError.

Comment: Huh. Well as you can see, I didn't test before I posted. :) I gotta say, that result surprises me. Any character after the backslash makes it work, but I guess there's no way to include a terminal backslash in a raw string.

Comment: See [Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash).

Comment: I tried that but it is replacing only first occurance. >>> path
'\\\\server path\\parent folder\\folder1'
>>> path.replace(r'\\', '\\')
'\\server path\\parent folder\\folder1'

Comment: Because, as others have noted, there was only one real instance of double backslashes in the string to begin with (the one at the start). They're just being doubled for display purposes by Python. It's the difference between `print path` and `print repr(path)` -- just typing `path` in the interactive shell is like `print repr(path)`. (Or, `print(repr(path))` in Python 3.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into, is that \ is an escape character. Instead of reading that as

replace '\\' with '\'

python is reading your argument as "replace the single backslash character with the single quotation mark character". The reason you are getting the error you are, is because python is ignoring your second single quotation mark because it thinks that is what you want it to do.

What you want is:

```
path.replace('\\\\', '\\')
```

you have to escape all backslashes because they are special.

Comment: I tried that but it is replacing only first occurence. >>> path
'\\\\server path\\parent folder\\folder1'
>>> path.replace('\\\\','\\')
'\\server path\\parent folder\\folder1'